# facing issue while installing oracle Database 11g on rhel5 And SOA

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, rhel5

[image]While installing required rpms for both SOA and Oracle the below rpms are conflicting with each other  `glibc-devel-2.5-49.x86_64.rpm` and `glibc-devel-2.5-24.i386.rpm` How can I fix it? one package gets installed successfully if I remove the other and vice-verse.

I need both of them to be installed on rhel5 64 bit operating system.

Comment: You need both 64- and 32- bit glibc development kits?   What is you OS, distribution, and version as well as if your platform is 32- or 64- bits.

Comment: Hi mdpc thanks for reply I have added the required information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using following process:

use `rpm -ivh --nodeps <packagename>` for i386 first and then for X86_64.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install two different numbered versions of the i386 and x86_64 packages without causing a lot of breakage.

Just install the same version of both packages.

```
yum install glibc-devel.{i386,x86_64}
```

After that, if you still receive this error, it's Oracle's fault and Oracle must fix it.